# Cell's contentView goes up side down on expanding collapsing section in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am making an accordion using UITableView. Everything is working fine except a case where number of rows is greater than 1, the view goes upside down on every tap on section or can say on every expansion.

I am unable to judge the reason behind it.[image: This is the actual view]

[image: The contentView is going upside down after expansion/collapsing]

Comment: what confusion do you have explain more.

Comment: first image shows the result that i want. but on expanding/collapsing the section, the inner content view of the section turns upside down as shown in image 2 where address line 2 is coming up where as it should have been down.

I am using the following code on tapping any section for expansion/collapsing

`tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)`

Comment: can you post your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath?